# Can not boot ubuntu and other linuxes

Tags: boot, command-line

I wanted to install Linux on my old Laptop, but whenever I try to boot it, it gets stuck on booting "command line" and looping in it. It is too fast to get any text but last line is "[ OK ] Reached target switch root". That is on Fedora, but it is  a similar thing on Ubuntu loop in "command line". I tried all my USB stick and 3 different programs to get OS on flash disk, I even tried DVD -  same result.
Especially on Ubuntu I can not see any "command line" just flashing screen (Ubuntu loading screen and black screen).

Windows installation boots normally.

Comment: What's the laptop model

Comment: Acer D250. I installed linux lot of times before, so it is very strange that it is doing what it is doing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after I successfully booted installation of Debian and installed it on the HDD I just tried to boot Ubuntu from USB one more time. It was same as before flashing screen and stuff, but after few seconds screen was flashing in longer delays and randomly so I let it few more seconds and it booted. I also connected LAN cable to the ethernet port, but I thing that can not be problem so I still do not know what happend, but it is working now so no problems at all.